# REST request across networks

Tags: networking, docker, docker-compose

Let's say I have two docker networks on the same machine. (Network-1 and Network-2)

On each network, I have containers. (Container-1-Network-1 and Container-1-Network-2 etc.)

I need to send a PUT request from Container-1(172.18.0.x) to Container-2 (172.19.0.x) but I get 'connection refused' because different networks can't communicate with each other. What are my options here? Can I move a container to another network, or merge networks into one or link containers somehow (in docker-compose.yml)?

Thanks.

Comment: This looks very similar to http://serverfault.com/q/830135/351549

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you should add the container to every network where it needs to communicate with other containers and each network should be isolated from each other. This is the default design of docker networking.

To add containers to another network, use:

```
docker network connect $network $container
```

An easier method when you have lots of containers to manage is to use docker compose to define which networks each container needs to belong to. This automates the `docker network connect` commands.

Comment: Thanks, any links on how to automate it with docker compose?

Comment: Docker's [networking with compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) covers this option nicely.